# Workflow Foundation 4.5 How to repeat activity on exception

Tags: c#, .net, workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4.5

I have activity that sometimes throws exception. I want to repeat it until it is successfully done.
How can I do that using Workflow Foundation 4.5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it by adding my activity into TryCatch activity, which is inside of DoWhile activity.